# What is an appropriate way to think of the 'self' keyword in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, messaging, self, message-passing

Regarding the semantics of `self`, is it more appropriate to say:

1. `self` is a keyword that holds a reference to whatever the current receiver is.
2. `self` is the *only* receiver in Ruby. When you call a method or invoke a class definition, the value bound to `self` becomes a copy of the value bound to that object. By value, I mean `unsigned long VALUE`

In other words, is it ever accurate to say that `myObj` is the actual receiver of a message, or is it instead the case that self is the true receiver and a copy of the `unsigned long VALUE` variable value that is bound to the `myObj` variable name gets bound to the `self` variable name?

In the latter case, you could only ever say that `self` is receiving a message, but `self` and `myObj` happen to reference the same object. (`self` is always the current object)

In the former case, you could actually say that the current object (message receiver) changes and Ruby just updates self accordingly.

Whats going on under the hood?

The reason I am concerned with this apparently arbitrary distinction is because I am trying to figure out how Ruby "passes a message"

Comment: What do you mean by the reference to `unsigned long VALUE`?  Is that something from the C implementation of MRI?

Comment: Yes, `VALUE` is the actual *value* that gets bound to the variable name. It is usually cast to a pointer and used in reference to a structure, unless the object has immediate value. (which is why its an `unsigned long` and not a pointer from the get-go)

Comment: If you're talking about that level of detail, why not look at the code to see what it does when it encounters `self` and when it dispatches a message/method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "pass a message" to an object, the message name is used to determine which method definition to execute. As arguments, that method definition receives both the rest of the message and the value to be used for `self`.

So from the point of view of the method code, `self` is just another parameter.  But in the Ruby source, instead of being declared in the method's formal parameter list, it's implicit.

In that sense, it's certainly not true that only `self` can receive messages, because the invocant of a message only *becomes* `self` after the message is received, and continues to be so only within the body of the method responding to that message.

Javascript, like Ruby, has a predefined name (`this` instead of `self`), but other languages deal with the invocant differently. Some let you pick your own name for it, which may differ between method definitions. Maybe the invocant is just the first formal parameter, as in Perl and Python; the answer to your question may be clearer in those languages. Or, since the syntax to specify the recipient of a message is normally different from the syntax of a passed-in argument, there might likewise be a special syntax for declaring an invocant parameter, as in Go.

Ruby has the additional wrinkle that a bareword which doesn't refer to a local variable is interpreted as a message with no explicit invocant, and automatically sent to `self`. Other than that, `self` is just another local variable (which happens to be predefined and read-only).

Comment: Is it the method itself that restores the value of self when it is done, or some external entity? I would imagine the latter, right?

Comment: It's the VM's stack management which maintains the value of self. As frames are pushed onto or popped from the stack, self is updated accordingly.

Comment: It's handled just like any other locally-scoped variable... the old value is restored when the method returns because the method's local scope is no longer there.  (Presumably it was popped off a stack of some sort.)

Answer (score 2):

Execution in Ruby always occurs within the scope of an instance of an object. `self` is a keyword which refers to the object which is the receiver of the current stack frame. At the top level, this is an instance of Object called `main`. Each time you pass a message to a receiver, the Ruby VM pushes a frame onto the stack which includes the receiver of that object, which it then exposes through the `self` keyword.

It's probably most accurate to think of `self` as "the receiver in the current stack frame". To that end, it's inaccurate to say that "self is the only receiver", as otherwise you could never change receivers!

Comment: can you point me to any resources about what it means to "push a frame onto the stack"? I am familiar with the concept of a stack, but I don't understand exactly what a 'frame' is. I am trying to learn more about how this stuff works under the hood, rather than how I use it as a programmer and Ruby is just my medium for doing so.

Comment: Call stacks are composed of stack frames. Each frame contains things like the function invoked and the variables the function was invoked with. In Ruby's case, it includes a reference to the receiver of the called method, which is then exposed as `self`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack